# Create a Picture Box and Labels for each object in a list, in Visual C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm creating a program that does a search for music albums from a fixed source, and returns a list of results as a JSON. I've successfully learnt to deserialise this object so it's usable in C#, but there's one thing I'm struggling with.

At the moment, I've manually created several picture boxes (for album art) and labels (for info.) for results, however the number of results is bound to vary depending on the users search.

Is there a way to perhaps do a '`for each`' loop that goes through each of the results, and can programmatically create the necessary picture box and label combos, in order to cater for fewer or more results?

I ask because I've seen applications perform a search and surely all of the results cannot just be filling preset labels/text boxes?

```
for each result in results:
{
    Create Picture Box;
    Create Labels;
}
```

Comment: You can use ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could to that. Assuming that your code is in a `WinForm` `Form`, use `PictureBox`, `Label`, and `Controls.Add`:

```
foreach (var result in results){
    PictureBox pb = ...;
    //initialize your PictureBox
    pb.Location = ...;
    pb.Image = ...;
    pb.Name = ...;
    // etc, then add
    Controls.Add(pb);

    //similarly for Label
    Label lbl = ...;
    //initialize your Label
    lbl.Location = ...;
    lbl.Text = ...;
    lbl.Name = ...;
    // etc, then add
    Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

One part you need to be careful in the dynamic creation is the `Location`. Make sure that the new controls' locations are not overlapped. If not, they may look like single control, because multiple controls are placed on top of one another.

Note: to do it more systematically, either putting the `PictureBox` and `Label` in a `FlowLayoutPanel`, and/or creating `UserControl` with a `PictureBox` and a `Label` on it would be a great idea. Then we only need to add the `UserControl` one by one, either directly to the `Form` or to the `FlowLayoutPanel` (please read the comments below this answer). My answer is a simplistic approach though, just to point out the idea that: yes, it is possibile to create dynamic controls in C# `WinForm`.

Comment: Maybe adfding them to a FlowLayoutPanel is a good idea. Also I would consider creating UserControls with a PB and Label on it..

Comment: @TaW ah, yes... to do it more systematically, then probably your suggestion, either to put the FlowLayoutPanel, and/or UserControl with a PB and Label on it would be a great idea. Then we only need to add the UserControl one by one, either directly to the Form or to the FlowLayoutPanel. Why not? :) My answer is a simplistic approach though, just to point out the idea.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your input. I will not be able to test your solutions for a couple of days, but from what I can interpret, it all makes sense to me. Thank you for answering so quickly and clearly. Charlie